# Cant get correct URL redirects to my website

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, https, dns, amazon-cloudfront

I have my own domain on NameCheap, lets call it example.com.
I also have a cloudfront distribution pointing to an s3 bucket which is serving only https traffic, lets call it myCloudfront.cloudfront.net

if i go to myCloudfront.cloudfront.net i am redirected to https://myCloudfront.cloudfront.net and everything looks fine.

On NameCheap I have a CNAME record with the following values:

```
Type         Host           Value                TTL
CNAME        www  myCloudfront.cloudfront.net    Automatic
```

The problem is that the only way I am redirected to my cloudfront distribution is when I specifically type in: https://www.example.com, if I leave out the www. or try to use http it either cant find the site or gets denied because it isnt https.

How can I set up the NameCheap site so that if the user types in any of the following they will be redirected to https://example.com:

```
example.com
www.example.com
http://example.com
http://www.example.com
https://www.example.com
```

Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

Hmm...seems to me, in NameCheap, you could do:

```
Host   Value               TTL
 @     your_server's_ip Automatic
www       @             Automatic
```

So, example.com and www.example.com will both point to example.com server.

On example.com, install Apache (I'm assuming example.com is a Linux server?), and set up a bunch of VirtualHosts in /etc/httpd/conf/httpd.conf, to handle forwarding and redirects between http -> https and https -> cdn, etc.
Something like this may work:

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerAdmin webmaster@example.com
    ServerName example.com
    Redirect https://myCloudfront.cloudfront.net/
</VirtualHost>
<VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerAdmin webmaster@example.com
    ServerName www.example.com
    Redirect https://myCloudfront.cloudfront.net
</VirtualHost>
<VirtualHost *:443>
    ServerAdmin webmaster@example.com
    ServerName example.com
    Redirect https://myCloudfront.cloudfront.net/
</VirtualHost>
<VirtualHost *:443>
    ServerAdmin webmaster@example.com
    ServerName www.example.com
    Redirect https://myCloudfront.cloudfront.net
</VirtualHost>
```

And you can get a lot more creative with your forwarding and redirects, if necessary.

The above four rules should cover:

```
http://example.com
http://www.example.com
https://example.com
https://www.example.com
```

Comment: i will definitely try the configuration on name cheap and see if that works. I can look into the apache server config too but thats definitely a little farther from my comfort zone

Comment: When I started w/ Apache a couple of years ago, I was clueless.  It's not too hard to figure out.  There's still plenty of stuff I don't understand, but the basics will come.